Finding the expectation of a categorical variable times a random amount
Say we have $J$ trading cards and each have a dollar value of $u_{j}$ and I am allowed to make 1 draw.
$$
u_{j} \sim N(\mu,1)
$$
Where the value of each trading card is independent and identically distributed.
The probability of drawing a trading card is a function of $u_{j}$.
We could specify this as a multinominal regression for the $J$ cards.
$$
\text{ln Pr}(C_i = j) = u_{j} - \text{ln} Z_i
$$
$$
Z_i = \sum_{j}^J e^{u_{j}}
$$
$Z_i$ is a normalizing value to ensure the probabilities add up to one.
Where $C_i$ is a categorical distribution where each probablity $p_j$ is given with the above formula. This is also the same as multinominal distribution with $n= 1$.
$$
C_i \sim Categorical(p_1^{[C_i = 1]} \cdots p_J^{[C_i = J]})
$$
The random value of the card would be:
$$
u_{1C_i} = \sum_j^J [C_i = j] * u_{j}
$$
If I wanted to know the expected value of dollar amount from drawing one card. How would I set that up?
$$
{\bf E} (u_{C_i}) = \int u_{C_i} f_{pdf}(u_{C_i})
$$
I am interested in setup what the integral or sum would look like? I understand that it will not simplify into a nice, closed form answer.
I was struggling with how to handle that the probability of $\text{Pr}(C_i = j)$ depends on the set $U = \{u_1, \cdots u_J\}$ and not just a particular $u_{j}$.
The motivating issue for this problem has to do with a complicated multinominal regression where there are random beta coefficients.

Hi JimB, Thank you. I am aware of the process of using monte carlo simulations and estimating ${\bf E}(u_{C_i}|U)$ and averaging over the random values of $U$  to get an approximation of ${\bf E}(u_{C_i})$. I am more interested in how to set the expectation up analytically even if it does not simplfy.

$\sum_{j}^J e^{u_{j}}$ is the sum of log normals which makes things very difficult to deal with exactly/symbolically (not to mention that its use in your objective is the reciprocal of the sum).  But symbolically one can see that $\mu$ will cancel out in the values of $p_j$ which means you can just deal with $N(0,1)$ and add in $\mu$ at the end.

If you are just interested in setting up the integrals for the expectation, then maybe the following does that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sum _{i=1}^J e^{u_i} u_i}{\sum _{i=1}^J e^{u_i}} 
    \times \prod _{i=1}^J \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (u_i-\mu)^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} du_1 \cdots du_J$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sum _{i=1}^J e^{v_i+\mu} (v_i+\mu)}{\sum _{i=1}^J e^{v_i+\mu}} \times \prod _{i=1}^J \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} v_i^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} dv_1 \cdots dv_J$$
$$=\mu+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sum _{i=1}^J e^{v_i} v_i}{\sum _{i=1}^J e^{v_i}} \times \prod _{i=1}^J \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} v_i^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }} dv_1 \cdots dv_J$$
Numerical integration will work fine for small values of $J$ but you'll likely need to perform simulations for values of $J$ greater than 4.

This uses the Law of the Unconscious  Statistician https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician.  I don’t like that wording but it does humble us into remembering that there’s more math in the background.
